# Badges: 'Tenacious' and 'Unsung Hero'

Tags: support, badges

Embarrassingly, I think I earned them, but obviously not.  What's it take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Tenacious: Zero score accepted answers: more than 5 and 20% of total
- Unsung Hero: Zero score accepted answers: more than 10 and 25% of total

The key words are "accepted answers" so the OP has to give you the checkmark, and "25% of total" which means at least 1/4 of your answers need to be in this state. Today, not a single person the site has this badge, because an answer that gets accepted almost always gets at least one vote. And for those correct answers that don't get a +1, they often don't get an "accepted" check because we have a lot of abandoned questions where the OP doesn't return to accept your answer.

Comment: Why don't we just get rid of those badges?

Comment: They have a purpose on other StackExchange sites, such as StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/226/unsung-hero

Comment: overlooked the word 'accepted'